# Having trouble with handle change function ,leaves one character out

Tags: reactjs, forms, error-handling, event-handling

So the handle change method works , but always forgets the last character of my string(when I type "test" it saves "tes") ,even when I am testing to see if there are value with the error in the function ,only pick up the error if there is one character left. Any suggestion would be helpful.

```
const [ tools, setTools ] = useState({
        name: props.values.name || '',
        description: props.values.description || '',
        notes: props.values.notes || '',
        downloadLink: props.values.downloadLink
    });
    
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setTools((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value 
        }));
        props.setEditValues(tools);
        if (!tools.name || !tools.description || !tools.downloadLink) {
            props.setError(true);
        }
        else {
            props.setError(false);
        }
        

    };

<TextField
                            error={props.error}
                            fullWidth
                            label='Name'
                            name='name'
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={tools.name}
                            variant='outlined'
                        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `tools` is not up to date in the scope of the `handleChange` function after you call `setState`.

Calling setState **does** update the `tools` value in the component state, but the `handleChange` function **needs to be recreated** so it would have the updated value.

One way to solve the issue is using a `useEffect` hook:

```
  const [tools, setTools] = useState({
    name: props.values.name || '',
    description: props.values.description || '',
    notes: props.values.notes || '',
    downloadLink: props.values.downloadLink
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setTools((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    props.setEditValues(tools);
    if (!tools.name || !tools.description || !tools.downloadLink) {
      props.setError(true);
    }
    else {
      props.setError(false);
    }
  }, [tools, props.setEditValues, props.setError]);

  <TextField
    error={props.error}
    fullWidth
    label='Name'
    name='name'
    onChange={handleChange}
    value={tools.name}
    variant='outlined'
  />
```

Another way is to create the updated `tools` value in the `handleChange` function scope and use it both for setting the component state and inside the function.

The function would look like this and you don't need `useEffect`:

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const nextTools = { ...tools, [name]: value };
    setTools(nextTools);
    props.setEditValues(nextTools);
    if (!nextTools.name || !nextTools.description || !nextTools.downloadLink) {
      props.setError(true);
    }
    else {
      props.setError(false);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt know you can do it like that . Problem fixed

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use onKeyUp insted of onChange:

```
<TextField
  error={props.error}
  fullWidth
  label='Name'
  name='name'
  onKeyUp={handleChange}
  value={tools.name}
  variant='outlined'
/>
```